# How to run python scripts from a terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I wrote a python file. Basically it takes all the city data and then let's you do fun things like biggest city per county in your state, densest cities, etc.

I can set up a main that goes through and says:

```
topNCitiesInCounty("Orange","CA",5)
densestCityInRegion("State","CA",5)
```

And it'll print it all to terminal.

I'd like to be able to run this dynamically. So I can just open up terminal type `python3` and go.

Once I'd initialized python I might go by and say 'import main' or whatever, and then I might go in and type `topNCitiesInCounty("Orange","CA",5)`.

This is a bit of a mess, I hope this makes sense. Basically, I know I can go into terminal and type `python3 main.py` and run my script. I'd like to be able to run functions dynamically from within there by only typing `python3` and seeing what I want from there. Doable?

Comment: Yes, you can `import main` and run your functions like `main.topNCitiesInCounty(blah, blah, blah)`

Comment: When I type import main it says 'No module named 'main''. But, my first function is def main():  Main isn't a class, it's just a function. Could that be it?

Comment: You should run Python _from the directory that contains `main.py`_. On Linux that would be `cd path/to/main_py && python3` and then `import main`. The `main` here is the name of the _file_ (`main.py` without the `.py`) - it has nothing to do with any functions or classes inside that file

Comment: Got it. My function was main, my file was not. Import fileName (without .py) and then run it as you say. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, If you want to execute python code interactively you should take the time to install IPython: http://ipython.org/. It provides a much friendlier interactive environment than the REPL provided by the python program.

Answer (score 0):

type `python` in your terminal,
then it will open up a python shell, where you can write instructions
one of them should be

```py
from main import topNCitiesInCounty
```

**instead of main you should put the name of the file in which your script is located**

which will load your method. then you will be able to run your method like this:

```py
topNCitiesInCounty("Orange","CA",5)
```